# Creating a simple crackme program in C++ problems with variable and input

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

So I am trying to learn C++ so I can learn some reverse engineering that why I am trying to create this simple crack me program to get a foundation going and not take someone else's project as I choose my own path. However I am using CodeBlocks as the other IDEs were not being cooperative and am enjoying it and has given me some error and two lines. Below is the following code. So there errors are the following:

`||=== Build: Debug in SimpleProgram (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\Programming\C++ Projects\simple programs\SimpleProgram\main.cpp||In member function 'int checker::processing(int)':|
D:\Programming\C++ Projects\simple programs\SimpleProgram\main.cpp|15|warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]|
D:\Programming\C++ Projects\simple programs\SimpleProgram\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
D:\Programming\C++ Projects\simple programs\SimpleProgram\main.cpp|22|error: 'x' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|`

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class checker{
public:
    int number;
    processing(int x){
        x = number;
        if ( number == 10 ){
            cout << "Well done!";
        } else {
            cout << "Keep trying!";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    checker cracking;
    cout << "Please enter in the correct number";
    cin >> cracking.processing(x);
    return 0;
}
```

[Image of the project and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU7AT.png)

Comment: It would be best to include the warnings and errors in your question as text, not an image.

Comment: Noted. Have added the errors above also if they are explanatory would you mind telling me or are you just going to leave it as is and downvote my question for learning.

Comment: What is your intent to use `processing()` as? a function or a constructor? for a function it doesn't even have the return type.

Comment: As a function, I never had to return anything before in writing other simple programs however this is one of my first. So what would I return?

Comment: advice: start by trying to understand in general (not specifically C++) what is a variable, a function, a parameter, a return value... and everything will become easier.

Comment: @CyberLable If you don't want to return anything mention `void` in front of it. Also you have not declared x in `main` if you want to pass that. If you intended to use a value, pass something like `processing(10)`.

Comment: I have completed C++ and C++ advance course in programming hub and had it down pat however I got busy and a couple days later I am trying to go off everything I have learnt yet have never had to return anything before, it's not the lack of myself just jumping in without learning it is something else to do with my capabilities I am trying to work through at the moment.

Comment: A parameter is something you *provide* to a function you are calling. Here in ``main()`` you try to provide ``processing()`` with a variable ``x`` which does not exist. Then assuming your function is called, you receive a parameter also named ``x`` and the first thing you do is to overwrite its value with something else, so this parameter is useless...

Comment: @Anirban166 I think you have pointed out my issue thanks. So how would I go about swapping my input to run as the argument? I am looking for it now to see if I can solve the problem. Sorry to everyone as I have not had any errors with debugging before.

Comment: @CyberLable Didn't get you. What do you mean by swapping your input? If you meant using an input variable as argument to `processing`, I did that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function always has a return type, even if your not attempting to return anything it will have the `void` signature. If your intent was to take input of a number passed from `main` and display it via a function in your class checker through an object of the same, this is how it would look like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class checker{
public:
    int number;
    void processing(int x)
    {
        if (x==10)
            cout << "Well done!";
        else 
            cout << "Keep trying!";
    }
};
int main()
{
    checker cracking;
    cout << "Please enter in the correct number \n";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cracking.processing(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Anirban166 , I understand what you have done and mean. I have learned to do this in the future thank you!

Comment: @CyberLable Anytime :) Also don't get angry on the community here - they just expect a certain degree of knowledge on the language tagged, and the question here was a bit trivial, but am sure you'll improve gradually - wish you the best of health!

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned the code up and included comments that serve as notes:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class checker{
public:
    void setnumber(int i){  //it's a good habit to put variables in private and access them with a public function
        this->number = i;
    };
    int processing(int x){  //x is just a placeholder value for whatever you put in here. You can't use it in the rest of the program
        if ( x == 10 ){
            cout << "Well done!" << endl;
            return 1;   //this condition indicates success
        } else {
            cout << "Keep trying!" << endl; //the endline just makes it so you aren't typing on the same line as the message
            return 0;   //this condition indicates success hasn't been reached yet
        }
    }
private:
    int number;
};

int main()
{
    checker cracking;
    cracking.setnumber(10);     //the number is set to 10

    int i, l;   //i is the guess number, l is a condition for the loop
    cout << "Please enter in the correct number" << endl;
    do{     //this loop sets it up so that you can have multiple tries
        cin >> i;
        l = cracking.processing(i);
    }while(l!=1);   //and this condition (the return value of processing(), breaks the loop on success
    return 0;
}
```

The main issue that popped out at me was the use of x.

Trying to set x to `number`. In functions, the parameters are just placeholder values for arguments that will be passed into later. Then later on when you tried to use x as an input in the `main()` program. You were calling that function (using it) and needed an int as input.

Don't worry. It's confusing in the beginning for everyone (*although to be fair, as you progress you'll just find new things to be confused about. It never really stops*). Keep at it and it'll all make sense in time.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot see where the cleanup stands in your example. Have you ever read this (https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-get) or this (https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices)? Why do you use ``std::endl`` instead of ``'\n'`` ? Why ``using namespace std;``? Shouldn't you consider a constructor to initialise ``number`` and compare ``x`` against ``number``? Why return ``int`` instead of ``bool``? I'm afraid this just makes the compiler happy but does not tend to lead towards good practices...

Comment: @prog-fh I cleaned the code up with regards to getting it to function as the program was intended to. I do see your points. No, I haven't read those before; thank you for the links. If you have any other advice, I'd love to hear it. As for the `int` instead of a `bool`, that happened more as a force of habit; I programmed in C long before I started looking into C++.